# Searching an Inflate implementation in Javascript that uses ArrayBuffer

Tags: javascript, implementation, unzip, inflate, arraybuffer

I'm desperately searching for a Javascript implementation of the Inflate algorithm that takes full advantage of the ArrayBuffer datatype.
Such an implementation would take an ArrayBuffer as input and give an ArrayBuffer as output,  without using those nasty binary strings while processing the data.

Do you know if such an implementation already exists? It would be of great use now that IE10 supports ArrayBuffer, as well as the other current browsers.

Comment: Probably not answering your question, but some people in the demo scene utilise PNG images for this. PNG normally uses deflate algorithm, and the decompression is handled in native code by the browser. Make your data into pixels, convert to PNG, serve to browser, then read off pixels from your hidden canvas.